# Viber program stopped working log file: start timer Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread 1

Tags: qt, qobject, viber

I was using VIBER application(cousin of SKYPE) when it stopped working.
I re-start my PC (it's installed only on my PC win7-kaspersky) but it doesn't work anymore.
The shortcut points to C:\Users\pardis\AppData\Local\Viber  where i have:

- launcher.db
- **Viber.exe**
- Viber.exe.log
- ViberUpdater.log
- ViberUpdater.cmd
- a lot of Qt*.dll files
  when i click on viber.exe nothing happens(the program doesn't open-nor it's process) but just Viber.exe.log is updated with this message:

> 1|<> :0 => QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads
>   started with QThread

Any idea what should i do to make it work again? thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without the source code

Comment: I don't have the source code. I do have the log file which is just one line added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Viber's installation folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Viber` on Windows 8), navigate to the folder with the name of the latest downloaded version (`5.1.1.15` in my case), and run `ViberSetup.exe`. This should update it to the latest version, keeping your data and resolving the issue.

Comment: thank you very much. I ran ViberSetup.exe and it began working

Comment: @Michelle Great. Please accept my answer to indicate it solved the problem for you and might do so for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, including the text from log file. I updated the program to the latest version and it started working again, it should work for you too.

Comment: without opening and running the program, did you update your Viber?

Comment: Download the installer from viber.com and run it. It searches and finds the old version and updates it. I haven't lost the log in data or anything, after the installer finished his job viber appeared as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the version that stopped working is the latest version. When I try to reinstall, it simply says: you already have Viber installed.
I guess the only answer is to completely uninstall Viber and then reinstall a fresh version. I found [a site](https://viber.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions) with all recent versions. So I could reinstall and update without losing any settings or syncs.

Comment: Further to the above, I found site with all recent versions. So I could reinstall and update without losing any settings or syncs. The link is: 
   https://viber.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions